# Share same private Azure DevOps repo with Azure boards on multiple projects

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, project-management, azure-repos, azure-boards

We have the same enterprise app that we sell to multiple customers. The source for the app is hosted in a private Azure DevOps Repo. But we manage each customer's implementation using a separate project for each customer with it's own work items.

Currently we have no way of linking commits to the Source in the Repo project to work items in the implementation project.

We don't want to have the repo in each implementation since that would be redundant and challenging to keep in sync.

Is there a way to handle this inside DevOps?

Comment: Use a single team project and have a different backlog for each customer by using teams.

Comment: @user1769627 Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for your feedback. I'll try that way and see how practical it is to track each customer's project status and progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently we have no way of linking commits to the Source in the Repo
>   project to work items in the implementation project.

For this issue, when you commit to the source in the Repo project, on the **Commit** page, you can choose to link to work items in other projects.

[image]

Or you can click `Add link` in the **Development** field of the work items in other projects.

[image]

Then on the **Add link** page, select the **Commit** link type, select your source repo, and select the commit you want to link.

[image]